# Excel 2016 New Window grayed out

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I want to have the same Excel file open in two windows.

I want things that I do in one window to appear in the same file that is being displayed in the other window.

My "New Window" button under "View" is grayed out.

[image: IMG:]

Comment: Why don't you use Split?

Comment: Because Split is also grayed out. See image.

Comment: Is your file currently opened or protected?

Comment: Are these options always greyed out, even when opening a new workbook?

Comment: New Window and Split are available with a new Excel file. I cannot figure out how to "unprotect" this workbook...

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? @Community bumped this ticket as it had no accepted answer. Review tab at top of Excel, then Protect Sheet is where you 'lock' spreadsheet functionality, is that what happened with this problematic file?

Comment: To unprotect the workbook, use the reverse of https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/protect-an-excel-file-7359d4ae-7213-4ac2-b058-f75e9311b599

Answer (score -1):

If the Cell is in edit mode the "New Window" under the "View" tab will be grayed out. Hit the "ESC" key and the "New Window" Grayed out should be undone